# Setting a MVC 5 Razor view <select asp-for = "xxx" </select> to a query

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating an MVC web core program in C# with ASP.NET. The program will consist of a few inputs to be inserted into a database which is already present (t-SQL).

My issue is that one of the fields needs to be a drop down list populated by a SELECT query. I only need this to be displayed as the drop down list so that the list of Facilities can change dynamically with the Db. My program works 100%, except for binding this drop down list. I do not need any data manipulation from the Facilities Db. Simply, just a list of what is there so that the user can select the appropriate name then that name will be stuck into the new Table I have created.

I can manually create a drop down all day, but that doesn't help me. The data connection has already been set elsewhere. The list will be in the WellNum portion of the code. I have combed and combed the internet and have yet to find a solution. Thank you for any help that is given.

Here is my View for Create.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label asp-for="WellNum" class="control-label"></label>
     <select asp-for="WellNum" class="form-control" /> 
     <span asp-validation-for="WellNum" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Aren't you missing the asp-items attribute? Like:

asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.WellNum, "value", "text"))"

Comment: No. Currently, what that view shows is a select list but has nothing contained within it

Comment: I'm confused with what you're trying to accomplish. Your list doesn't contain anything because there are no html option tags or asp SelectList items. In order to get the select tag to have values, you need to specify whether or not they're coming from a db or hard-coded...they still need specified.

Comment: Yes. that is the cshtml that I currently have. It's not appropriate for what I'm trying to accomplish but I figured you guys would want to see what I currently have. I don't need to hardcode the list. the list needs to come from a Db but it seems that all of that code needs to be in the Create.cshtml file

Comment: Does your view have a model tied to it? Do you have @model WellNum at the top? If so, then use the model to populate the options. If not, then you'll have to set the SelectList values in the code-behind. Either way, you'll never see anything in your list without the <option> tags or the html helper asp-items like I stated above. Go here and see an example:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39531453/populating-dropdown-in-asp-net-core

Comment: yes I do have the @model at the top of the code. After looking at the link you provided the problem is that it is a manually populated list. I need my list to be generated by a Db select query

Comment: Ok, I'm assuming the model contains a collection, such as IList, IEnumerable, IQueryable, etc.., that you want to use for your dropdown? Or is it a List<SelectListItem>?

Comment: List<selectListIem> is what I am trying to go with.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have a class called `Person` that looks like this:

```
public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

And need to display a list of people received from the Database/Repository

My controller is as follows:

```
 public class PeopleController : Controller
    {
        // GET: People
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Person> people = Db.GetAllPeople();
            return View(people); //This is how you pass your strongly typed data to the view
        }
    }
```

While creating a view, tightly bind your view to the List data model by adding this in the beginning of the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.Person>//Fully qualified name
```

and generate your dropdown list as

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label asp-for="WellNum" class="control-label"></label>
     <select asp-for="WellNum" class="form-control" /> 
         @foreach (var item in Model) //This creates a dropdown of all the peoples names received from the database
         {
             <option value=item.Name>item.Name</option>
         }
     <span asp-validation-for="WellNum" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Or

Replace the foreach loop with

```
@Html.DropDownList("WellNum",new SelectList(Model,"Name","Name"))
```

which will generate the following html

```
<select id="WellNum" name="WellNum">
    <option value=valueField>dataTextField</option>
    <option value=valueField>dataTextField</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Comment: This is where I am having the disconnect, I believe. In your example (much appreciation btw), Where you have List<Person> people = Db.GetAllPeople(); is the function GetAllPeople where I would have my string query = "select suchandsuch from MyTable";? My issue is figuring out where to insert my query to select the rows that I need to populate the List<>

Comment: also my code looks almost identical to yours except in the view since I haven't gotten far enough along to display the loop to show the attributes within the List<>

Comment: You can create a separate layer to implement your database related activities, the query can be inserted in your repository layer