# Bind Dropdownlist with TagHelpers

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to create a dropdownlist and bind with viewbag using ASP.NET Core tag helpers.

I can bind the dropdownlist using:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Area_id", 
                   new SelectList(ViewBag.Areas, "Value", "Text"), 
                   "Select an Area")
```

But I have hard time to use ASP.NET Core tag helper on HTML "Select":

```
<select asp-for="" asp-items="" />
```

My code always has red line under `asp-for="Area_id"` saying `Area_id` is not accessible. I tried to use `asp-for="Id"` and still doesn't work. The `GetAreas()` function works fine. Please help!

Model classes:

```
public class DegreeViewModel
{
    public int Degree_id { get; set; }
    public int Area_id { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Areas { get; set; }
}
        
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var vm = new DegreeViewModel();
    vm.Areas = GetAreas();
    return View(vm);
}
```

Controller:

```
private MyContext _context;

[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public int Area_id  { get; set; }

[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public int? Degree_id { get; set; }     

public IActionResult Index()
{
     var vm = new DegreeViewModel();
        vm.Areas = GetAreas();
        return View(vm);
}

public List<SelectListItem> GetAreas()
{
    var Areas = (from a in _context.Degrees
                 select new SelectListItem { Text = a.Area_name, Value = a.Area_id.ToString() }).ToList();
    Areas.Add(new SelectListItem("Select", "0"));
    return Areas;
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model DegreeViewModel

<form asp-action="GetResult" asp-controller="Home" method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
   
        <label  class="control-label">Areas</label>
        <select asp-for="Area_id" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Areas,"Value","Text"))"  />
        <span asp-validation-for="Area_id" class="text-danger"></span>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: There is an example showing how binding of select controls with tag helpers at [here](https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-built-in-tag-helpers/#select).

Answer (score 0):

The model's type you passed to page is `IEnumerable`, So you can't use `asp-for="Area_id"`. You need to use `@foreach(var item in model){}` and then `asp-for="item.Area_id"`. Because your question is how Bind Dropdownlist with TagHelpers and don't provide the post method, So i will just show how to use TagHelpers to bind dropdownlist.

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            //If you want to use `<select>`, you need to use specific class `SelectListItem`
           
           List<SelectListItem> test = new List<SelectListItem>();
                foreach (var item in GetAreas())
                {
                    test.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.Area_name, Value = item.Id.ToString() });
                }

            ViewBag.Areas = test;

            return View();
        }
```

**page**

```
<select asp-items="@ViewBag.Areas" name="xxx" Id="xxx"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am going to create a search form with the dropdownlist selectedvalue as search term  and the bottom part is the search results so my index.cshtml is IEnumerable model type. The post method is also calling the Index() method. I did the same way in asp.net MVC app and tried to replicate it in asp.net core app. I removed the asp-for taghelper and now the dropdownlist in the view does not bind any data.

Comment: I think you can use `viewBag` to pass the IEnumerable data and just pass data from controller to view. `dropdownlist` has some different between `.net MVC` and `.net core`, You can refer to [link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0),[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39531453/populating-dropdown-in-asp-net-core),I hope my answer can help you.

Comment: Thanks. Now I created a DegreeViewModel to include the list of Areas. But my dropdownlist still does not bind to the data. I create a separate post method called GetResults() to return search results later. Please help.

Comment: Never mind. I guess I cannot use asp-for tag helper in the dropdownlist for IEnumerable Model. I removed the asp-for and only bind the asp-items to the viewbag.areas and my code works now. Thanks for the helps.